# How to redirect or force page if mysql returns nothing in a query

Tags: php, mysql

working on a small project and having a small problem. i am querying mysql, i am able to get the array and everything works well but i am adding a additional condition if returns 0 or id does not match the query then redirect.

This is what i have so far.

```
$q = "SELECT TEST.*,
             EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID                     
        FROM TEST
        LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE ON TEST.EMP_ID = EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID 
        WHERE ITEM_ID=".$db->qstr($item_id);

if(!$item_id = $db->execute($q)){
    force_page('system', 'Nothing found');
    exit;
} else {
    $view = $item_id->GetArray();
}

return $view;
}
```

so the above returns the array, query grabs $item_id from the url so it could be anything. i would like to check if that id exists if not then force the page as shown in the above. any suggestion on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add the code of force_page()? Might clear up what exactly you want :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect you can use `header` function

```
header("Location: put_your_url_here");
```

e.g.

```
header('Location: /mypage.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any function like `force_page();` in php
You need to redirect like `header("Location: Your_url");`

And If you have function `force_page();` please post code of that.

Comment: hey thank you for your response, i add new reply below

Comment: your $item_id is response from db. yah? then if $item_id is empty you should do your job.

Comment: i tried this too still not redirecting, any other solutions?

Comment: please post your $db->execute($q) response.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function such as `force_page` in PHP. You can use `header` to redirect user to another page. Modify your `if` condition as

```
if(!$item_id = $db->execute($q)){
    header("Location: url_to_redict");
    die();
}
```

Comment: i have a function for force_page however i have change it to header but it's not redirecting.

Comment: Are you `echo`ing anything before the `header` function?

Comment: nope nothing is being echoed.  however if i add a statement like this if($item_id =="" || !$rs $db->execute($q)){  // then it redirects if the id in the url is empty but it's not redirecting if i entered an invalid id that is not in the database

Comment: Your condition `!$item_id = $db->execute($q)` would execute only if `$item_id` is FALSE. Try changing it to `empty` or `NULL` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location: Your_url");` will help you to redirect based on your condition.but make sure that you have not echoed any thing before the header otherwise it won't redirect.